# Idiomatically creating a multi-value Map from a Stream in Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, multimap

Is there any way to elegantly initialize and populate a multi-value `Map<K,Collection<V>>` using Java 8's stream API?

I know it's possible to create a single-value `Map<K, V>` using the [`Collectors.toMap(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) functionalities:

```
Stream<Person> persons = fetchPersons();
Map<String, Person> personsByName = persons.collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
```

Unfortunately, that method won't work well for possibly non-unique keys such as a person's name.

On the other hand, it's possible to populate a multi-value `Map<K, Collection<V>>` using [`Map.compute(K, BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V>>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Stream<Person> persons = fetchPersons();
Map<String, Set<Person>> personsByName = new HashMap<>();
persons.forEach(person -> personsByName.compute(person.getName(), (name, oldValue) -> {
    Set<Person> result = (oldValue== null) ? new HashSet<>() : oldValue;
    result.add(person);
    return result;
}));
```

Is there no more concise way of doing this, e.g. by initializing and populating the map in one statement?

Comment: Isn't this a textbook use case for groupingBy ?

Comment: @PatrickParker yeah, you and Holger are right. I've never used that method much.

Comment: @Patrick Parker: yes, it’s a perfect use case for `groupingBy`, which [is a practical application of `computeIfAbsent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#908). Of course, on the application side, `groupingBy` is preferable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use `forEach`, it’s much simpler to use `computeIfAbsent` instead of `compute`:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> personsByName = new HashMap<>();
persons.forEach(person ->
    personsByName.computeIfAbsent(person.getName(), key -> new HashSet<>()).add(person));
```

However, when using the Stream API, it’s preferable to use `collect`. In this case, use `groupingBy` instead of `toMap`:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> personsByName =
    persons.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, Collectors.toSet());
```